# Why keyboard language programmatic change not affect even if no any error in my C# code?

Tags: c#, keyboard

I use following code to change keyboard language to US English. The code runs without error, but the language is still not changed on taskbar display.

```
        var original = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
        var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
        var language = InputLanguage.FromCulture(culture);
        if (InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.IndexOf(language) >= 0)
        {
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = language;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.DefaultInputLanguage;
            return false;
        }
```

What's I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the code goes into the `if` branch and not the `else`?

Comment: Eric J Yes it goes and returns true from my function.